# The pointer variables overflows when they store integers larger than 1024 and some adresses seem to be locked.in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, integer-overflow

How do I get to write to 2D pointers where I have `pnumber[2%4][2%4]` and how can I get `pnumber` with more than 3 ciphers to be displayed?

I'm making a program to write pascals triangle in C. 
When the pointer `pnumbers[i][j]` have both `i` and `j = 2 mod 4`, except for when i and `j = 2`, then my program won't write to the address and give the error message:

```
pascals triangle: malloc.c:2406: sysmalloc: Assertion '{old_top == initial_top (av) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
Aborted.
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int factorial(int p) {
    if (p>=1) {
        return p*factorial(p-1);
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}

int NchooseM(int n, int m) {
    return factorial(n)/(factorial(n-m)*factorial(m));
}

int main() {

    int n =7;
    int x = n-2;
    int i, j, k;
    /*
    printf("How many rows of Pascals triangle do you want to write?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    */
    int **pnumbers;
    pnumbers = (int **) malloc(n  *sizeof(int *));

    /* Allocate memory for storing the individual elements in a row */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        pnumbers[i] = (int *) malloc(i * sizeof(int));
    }

    pnumbers[0][1] = 1;

    /* Calculating the value of pnumbers[k][l] */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            pnumbers[i][j] = NchooseM(i,j);
        }

/*
        if (!(i % 4 == 2 && i != 2))
            for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                pnumbers[i][j] = NchooseM(i,j);

        } else if (i > 2) {
            for (j = 0; j <= i-1; j++) {
                pnumbers[i][j] = NchooseM(i,j);
        }
        }
*/
    }

    /* Writing out the triangle */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (k = 0; k <= x; k++){
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            printf("%d ", pnumbers[i][j]);
        }
        x = x-1;
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        free(pnumbers[i]);
    }
    free(pnumbers);
  return 0;
}
```

When I avoid writing to these addresses and just print them out I get some seemingly random integer at these memory addresses.
Also when avoid these addresses and just print out so many rows that I get some spots with a higher integer with more than 3 siphers, it seems to overflow - and I don't see the logic behind it. 
[The result of running the second code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag0lb.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int factorial(int p) {
    if (p>=1) {
        return p*factorial(p-1);
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }

}

int NchooseM(int n, int m) {
    return factorial(n)/(factorial(n-m)*factorial(m));
}

int main() {

    int n =20;
    int x = n-2;
    int i, j, k;
    /*
    printf("How many rows of Pascals triangle do you want to write?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    */
    int **pnumbers;
    pnumbers = (int **) malloc(n  *sizeof(int *));

    /* Allocate memory for storing the individual elements in a row */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        pnumbers[i] = (int *) malloc(i * sizeof(int));
    }

    pnumbers[0][1] = 1;

    /* Calculating the value of pnumbers[k][l] */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        /*
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            pnumbers[i][j] = NchooseM(i,j);
        }
        */

        if (!(i % 4 == 2 && i != 2))
            for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                pnumbers[i][j] = NchooseM(i,j);

        } else if (i > 2) {
            for (j = 0; j <= i-1; j++) {
                pnumbers[i][j] = NchooseM(i,j);
        }
        }
    }

    /* Writing out the triangle */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (k = 0; k <= x; k++){
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            printf("%d ", pnumbers[i][j]);
        }
        x = x-1;
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        free(pnumbers[i]);
    }

    free(pnumbers);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first time through this loop `for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { pnumbers[i] = (int *) malloc(i * sizeof(int)); }` allocates 0 bytes of memory.

Comment: The cast to the return value of `malloc()` is redundant at best, an error at worst. As you included `<stdlib.h>` it's redundant in this specific case.

Comment: Thanks @pmg, changing `for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { pnumbers[i] = (int *) malloc(i * sizeof(int)); }` to `for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        pnumbers[i] = (int *) malloc((i+1) * sizeof(int));
    }` fixed the 2 mod 4 problem :) 
But row number 13 is still quite messed up.

Comment: @Henka even with `i+1` the statement `pnumbers[0][1] = 1;` accesses out of bounds. Dimension 1 means `[0]` is the last valid index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[But row number 13 is still quite messed up.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59338149/the-pointer-variables-overflows-when-they-store-integers-larger-than-1024-and-so#comment104874441_59338149)

Code is experiencing `int` overflow and thus *undefined behavior* (UB).

With 32-bit `int` and `int factorial(int p)`, `p > 12` oveflows the `int` range.

Code could use a wider integer type  (`long long` works up to `p==20`), but improvements can be made at `NchooseM()` to avoid overflow for higher values.

Something like the below.  Works up to `int n = 30;`

```
int NchooseM(int n, int m) {
  // return factorial(n)/(factorial(n-m)*factorial(m));
  int nm = 1;
  int den = 1;
  for (int i = m+1; i <= n; i++) {
    assert(INT_MAX/i >= nm);
    nm *= i;
    assert(nm % den == 0);
    nm /= den++;
  }
  return nm; 
}
```

Tried `unsigned long long` and works up to `int n = 62;`

---

Edit: Another bug:

I "fixed" by initializing all to 1, yet I suspect something remains amiss in `/* Calculating the value of pnumbers[k][l] */ for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {` code.

```
pnumbers[i] = malloc((i + 1) * sizeof pnumbers[i][0]);
for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
  pnumbers[i][j] = 1;
}
```

---

Aside: rather than `pnumbers[i] = (int *) malloc((i+1) * sizeof(int));`, consider below with no unneeded cast nor trying to match the right type.

```
pnumbers[i] = malloc(sizeof pnumbers[i][0] * (i+1));
```